# Are Hindu temples designed in such a way that the spiritual energy flows out of the garbagriha?

Tags: temple, architecture

This website talks about the [features of a Hindu temple](http://www.ancient.eu/Hindu_Architecture/)

> Worshippers consider that energy flows out in all directions from the
>   *garbhagriha*, and this is reflected in the architecture of the
>   surrounding parts of the temple.

Is this just a belief? Or, is it related to the architecture of the temple?

Comment: How are you asking for an objective opinion on something which cannot be measured physically (spiritual energy)?

Comment: Good question, because it is being related to the architecture of the temple. And, hence there is a possibility of an objective analysis if this is not a mere belief.

Answer (score 1):

It is a belief and the architecture is likewise.
It is often told that in older times(like 500-600) years ago temples were not just made.
An idol was selected. And often place with copper underneath it to channelise the energy around it. The temple hence was built around this energy chakra and the idol. 
So the temple is for the idol but not the idol for the temple. This meant the main focus was the energy of faith flowed from one point to everywhere(and hence the ritual of a parikrama clockwise).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Each and every part of the temple is created based on architecture principle which ultimately leads to spiritual energy source. Let me answer for specific part of temple - Dome.

If you look around the web and find for the shape of nuclear reactor then the answer should be - Dome. Because it is proven that Dome shape is used to produce energy. So, all the Jyotirling are have Dome shape as Ling itself is source of energy.